# Docker Container Copying Host Local Files

Tags: .net, dockerfile

I am using visual studio 2022, and have the following docker file, I am trying to include additional files and in a different directory than my application is being deployed. I have tried multiple ways to copy test.txt, but none seem to work.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Testing/Testing.csproj", "Testing/"]
COPY ["C://text.txt", "C://test.txt"]

RUN dotnet restore "Testing/Testing.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Testing"
RUN dotnet build "Testing.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Testing.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Testing.dll"]
```

Comment: We dont know what files are on your host, or your `docker build` command to see the context, or if you have `.dockerignore` that prevents those files from being copied... Please clarify these items

Comment: I am using visual studio to deploy to docker desktop, so its auto building this: docker build -f "C:\Users\user\source\Testing\Testing\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t testing:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=Testing" "C:\Users\user\source\Testing"

Comment: Okay, then you cannot copy any files outside of `C:\Users\user\source\Testing` folder

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to copy files from `C://`.

Dockerfiles cannot access files outside of its context. This is usually the current directory, passed by the `.` in the command `docker build -t myapp .` . Therefore, you need to have that file next to the `Dockerfile` **and** not have `test.txt` in any `.dockerignore` file, as this will prevent it from being passed to the Docker daemon context (anything available to the `COPY` directive)

Only then, can you do `COPY ["text.txt", "/test.txt"]`, for example

Plus, dotnet runtime layer is Linux based, by default, I believe, so there is no "C drive" that Docker even knows about.